# find duplicate and execute script on a match

Tags: perl, bash, grep

I am trying to create a script to parse a log file and find duplicate matches of a specific part of each line and if a duplicate exists I need to execute a script on the first line that matches the duplication. My log details are:

```
#: 177          101 User 1 Channel: SIP/101
#: 178          117 User 2 Channel: SIP/117
#: 179          150 User 3 Channel: SIP/150
#: 356          166 User 4 Channel: SIP/166
#: 387          117 User 2 Channel: SIP/117
```

I'd like to find duplicates based on the SIP/ part of the log file but I will need to execute a script based on the # part of the log file. Based on this log I need to execute a script for the #: 178 line.

So far I have used

`egrep -o ".{50}SIP.{4}"`

to find the duplicates based on the SIP/ section of the line. It's not clear to me how I can then get the entire line to get the #: 178 and generate the script to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '$NF in array && !dup[$NF] { print array[$NF]; dup[$NF]++ } { array[$NF]=$2 }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
178
```

Comment: You should be able to do this in one pass - on each record, check if the corresponding array entry exists and print it before you set the array value, and add a second array that you use to track whether an entry has already been printed (to avoid printing again on the third and subsequent occurrences).

Answer (score 1):

A one pass solution. It takes advantage of `uniq` supporting skip-fields and repeated-only flags

```
sed -n '/SIP/{s/^#:\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*SIP\/\([0-9]\+\)/\1 \2/;p}' file.txt | sort -k2,2 -n | uniq -f 1 -d | cut -f1 -d ' '
```

Comment: Good idea =) Might I suggest to add the `-n` flag to sort?

Comment: Another minor suggestion: perhaps use the `p` flag in sed's substitute command and use the `-n` command line option? This is to generalize and ignore lines that don't match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
grep -nE "$(sed -ne '/^#/s/.*SIP\/\([0-9]*\)$/\1/p' log.txt | sort -n | uniq -d | paste -sd '|')"  log.txt | head -n 1
```

This will print (based on you example file):

```
2:#: 178          117 User 2 Channel: SIP/117
```

The main command is the `grep -nE "$(...)" log.txt`, which will search your log file for repeated lines and print them (the regular expression for this is generated dynamically, and I'll explain it below). The output is then piped to `head -n 1` to print only the first line. The `-n` flag to the `grep` command prints the real line number of the match, you can remove it if you don't need that.

To generate the regular expression, we have 4 commands.

1. The `sed -ne '/^#/s/.*SIP\/\([0-9]*\)$/\1/p' log.txt` will extract only the SIP numbers that are present on lines that start with `#`.
2. The output of sed (a list of numbers) is then piped to be sorted numerically
3. After it is sorted, we can use the `uniq -d` command to only print duplicate lines.
4. Finally, we join all the numbers together in a single line with the `paste` command, we use the `-d '|'` option to specify that we want the numbers separated by '|'s, which is a regular expression operator for OR.

Therefore, the regex will find lines that have any one of the duplicate numbers.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: When I ran your command it returned `#: 177          101 User 1 Channel: SIP/101`.

Comment: How did you run it? Did you create a `log.txt` file with the exact copy of the OP's example? And I find it weird that the original line number is missing from the start of the line =S

Comment: Yes the log.txt is exactly as OP's log file.

Answer (score 0):

AWK works well for this kind of thing.

Here is a readable, one-pass solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

{
    sip = $3
    script = $2

    count[sip]++

    if (count[sip] == 1) {
        scripts[sip] = script
    }
    else if (count[sip] > 1) {
        to_run[sip] = scripts[sip]
    }
}

END {
    for (sip in to_run) {
        print to_run[sip]
    }
}
```